# (Regular (but not Lindelöf)) + (??some property??)=> Normal

Tags: general-topology

Does anyone know any sufficient condition to a regular topology (but not Lindelöf) to be normal?

Comment: I know that regular + paracompact implies normal, but I don#t know right now if there is a non-Lindelöff space.

Comment: Well, an uncountable discrete space is regular and paracompact, but not Lindelöff.

Comment: @Stefan: In fact a paracompact **Hausdorff** space is already normal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I know, because a paracompact Hausdorff space is regular.

Comment: @Stefan: I’m just emphasizing that paracompactness is a *big* sledgehammer here. Unfortunately, I don’t know of one that’s much smaller.